# Tag merge / synonym request: [ux] → [user-experience]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

Please merge tag [ux](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ux) (13 questions) into [user-experience](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-experience) (68), and make them synonyms.

Neither of the tags has wiki, but questions in both are about [user experience (UX)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_experience).

---

Preference for master tag is because it has much more questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so there's an answer...I did this.

And, for the record, even if [ux](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ux) had more questions, I'd make the master [user-experience](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-experience) since it's more descriptive.